# How to count the total number of sheets in an Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I am reading a excel file using python.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

xls = pd.ExcelFile('D:\DirectoryProject\Mapping.xlsx')
```

It has several number of data sheets which I don't know. How can I count the total number of sheets in `Mapping.xlsx` file using Python?

Answer (score 63):

#### `openpyxl`

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx') 
res = len(wb.sheetnames)
```

#### `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
res = len(xl.sheet_names)
```

#### `xlrd`

```
import xlrd

# use on_demand=True to avoid loading worksheet data into memory
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xlsx', on_demand=True)
res = len(wb.sheet_names())  # or wb.nsheets
```

Comment: Can this be flagged as answered, it works and is simple (python) for me

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answer -

```
len(pd.read_excel(r"D:\DirectoryProject\Mapping.xlsx", sheet_name="None"))
```

This way you can get the number of sheets as well.

Comment: This solution works, but it involves reading all the worksheets into memory (via a dictionary) before counting the number of sheets. As such, it appears overkill.

Comment: that is true, in that case we can use xlrd's on_demand option as you have mentioned in your answer